# Inserting SQL script into PutSQL-processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a `CREATE TABLE` SQL script in a `PutSQL`-Processor.

So far I have identified no other way to set the SQL script than to do it manually. Is there an option to get and set the SQL script for a processor automatically at runtime?

My ideal process would look like this:

1. Success message of previous processor
2. Get SQL file from a specific GitHub branch (or from a local file) and insert it into the PutSQL-processor
3. Run PutSQL-processor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PutSQL reads the contents of an incoming FlowFile as the SQL command to run.

So you could use InvokeHTTP to pull a file down over HTTP, or GetFile to get a local file from the filesystem, or ListFTP+FetchFTP to get a file from FTP.

As long as the contents of the file are valid SQL statements, you can send this straight in to PutSQL and it will run the SQL.